# What can be a checklist when expo livereload stops?

Tags: expo, metro-bundler

First, major thing I have to state is, I don't know how to reproduce the problem.

Only information I have is, when working with devices within the same wifi network  with my computer, in the first couple saves' reloads work just as expected. But suddenly it stops to catch the new saves.

Since I don't know what particular action causes livereload to stop working, I don't know what to check either.

One particular information that may give a clue is, if I reload from the device manually, it executes the pre-save version. Which makes me think, the save is not caught thats why new version is not compiled either. (Please remember, this happens after a couple of proper reloads, that is why I don't think it is a setup issue. Even it was, I did not touch the setup that expo-cli brings while generating the project, except "yarn add"ing new packages as one may expect.)

The question is, what can be a checklist when expo livereload stops?